# How to upgrade Windows 2008R2 German to Windows 2012 R2 English

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2008-r2, language, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to update several Windows 2008 R2 servers to Windows 2019 - we all have to these days... And yes, I'm aware that I have to go via Windows 2012 R2, that's not the issue:

There's one server in the pack that got installed by someone else using the GERMAN localized version, for whatever reason. Trying to update that machine using the standard English 2012 R2 ISO I receive the error that I cannot update from a German to an English version. To be honest, I don't care for a localized server OS, so I would prefer the server to be English after the updates.
Question is: what's the preferred way to do that, if I can do it?
Would installing the en-us language pack help in my situation?
Or do I have to live with that language version until we decide to setup the server from scratch?

Comment: You can probably change the language pack once you're in Windows 2012/2019

Comment: Yes that would be my "fallback scenario". Main problem with that is that currently I don't have a German 2012 R2 ISO. But thanks anyways

Comment: @LotharMueller - Windows Server 2012 R2 isn’t licensed specifically to a language, you can use the same source, to download the appropriate ISO.  One of the requirements to upgrade 2008 to 2012 is the language must be identical.  There is no way to bypass that requirement

Comment: An alternative to upgrading to 2012 R2, is export the server configuration, and reinstall the proper version of Windows Server.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for your input; in regards to your first comment: that's what I would have loved to do but 2012 isn't showing up in our enterprise portal, only all kinds of Srv 2019 versions. But nevermind, your 2nd comment points exactly to what I decided to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this can't be done. So we'll have to either look for a localized installation ISO or start from scratch with a new Windows 2019 setup then port over the original configuration. We decided to got for the latter.